# how to call stored procedure with multiple in and out parameters using entity manager

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jpa, ejb, java-ee-6

We are facing an issue while calling the stored procedure from the application.
The database is `oracle 10g`
This proc has 2 input parameters and 2 output parameters.

Input 1:- DB-List
Input 2:- String

Output 1:-Again a DB-List
Output 2:- Number

When we are trying to use

```
 Query q = session.createSQLQuery("{call proc_name(?,?,?,?)}");
```

We cannot distinguish between `in` parameters and `out` parameters.
So how should we handle it by using this.

Also,
We tried to use callable statement as follows:

```
Session session = (Session) getEntityManager().getDelegate();
SessionImpl sessionImpl = ((SessionImpl) getEntityManager().getDelegate());
Connection cc = sessionImpl.connection();
CallableStatement callableStatement = null;

callableStatement = cc.prepareCall("{call proc_name(?,?,?,?)}");
ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("DB_LIST",callableStatement.getConnection());
ARRAY paramArray = new ARRAY(descriptor, callableStatement.getConnection(), array);
callableStatement.setArray(1, paramArray);
callableStatement.setString(2, "N");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.ARRAY, "DB_RETURN_LIST");
callableStatement.registerOutParameter(4, Types.INTEGER);
// executing the query
callableStatement.execute();
```

We get the following error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
$Proxy50 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection
```

Can you please provide some suggestions.

This is the Entity Manager that we are using

```
public abstract class GenericDAO<T, ID extends Serializable> implements IGenericDAO<T, ID> {
private final Class<T> persistentClass;
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "firstPersistenceUnit")
@Produces
private EntityManager entityManager;

public void setEntityManager(final EntityManager entityManager) throws DataAccessException {
this.entityManager = entityManager;
}

public EntityManager getEntityManager() throws DataAccessException {
return entityManager;
}
}
```

Here is the entry in the Persistance.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
<persistence-unit name="firstPersistenceUnit">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/firstDataSource</jta-data-source>
<class>com.domain.Branch</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
<validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>

<persistence-unit name="secondPersistenceUnit">
<provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/secondDataSource</jta-data-source>
<class>com.domain.PocJeeCounty</class>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
<validation-mode>AUTO</validation-mode>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: I think the problem is not with the stored procedure, is with your Entity Manager.Can u paste your complete code.

Comment: Hi @SajanChandran i have added the code for the entity manager as well as the persistance.xml that we are using

Comment: We tried this using unwrap as well as session.doWork.
But its still giving us the error :- 
java.lang.Exception: javax.ejb.EJBException: java.lang.ClassCastException: $Proxy66 cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.[/code]This happens specifically when we try to get the connection for Array Descriptor.
ArrayDescriptor descriptor = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(DB_LIST",callableStatement.getConnection());

Answer (score 3):

Dont use second way, instead create and define query and query parameters using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery and @StoredProcedureParameter. Following is the code for your requirement

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(  
    name="PROC_NAME",  
    procedureName="proc_name",  
    returnsResultSet=true/false,  
    parameters={  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="param1",name="p1",direction=Direction.IN,type=Integer.class),  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="param2",name="p2",direction=Direction.IN,type=Timestamp.class),  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="param3",name="p3",direction=Direction.OUT,type=String.class),  
        @StoredProcedureParameter(queryParameter="param4",name="p4",direction=Direction.OUT,type=Integer.class)  
    }  
    )
```

and use em.createNativeQuery() method