# calling stored procedure having mulitple output parameter from java using hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, hibernate-mapping

I am trying to call a stored procedure using hibernate . Here is the mapping :-

```
<hibernate-mapping>
   <sql-query name="myprocedure" callable="true">
    <return alias="ev" class="TestDataBean">
        <return-property name="city" column="CITY"/>
        <return-property name="country" column="COUNTRY"/>
    </return>
    <![CDATA[CALL  myprocedure(?,?)]]>
</sql-query>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Store procedure is:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE myprocedure(
    CITY OUT VARCHAR,
    COUNTRY OUT VARCHAR)
IS
BEGIN
  SELECT * INTO CITY,COUNTRY
  FROM TESTTABLE

END myprocedure;
```

Java code is:

```
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("myprocedure");
List results = query.list();
for (Object object : results) {
    TestDataBean test = (TestDataBean)object;
}
```

But I am getting this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries:myprocedure
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:545)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1859)
at CallStoredProcedure.callOracleStoredProcOUTParameter(CallStoredProcedure.java:37)
at CallStoredProcedure.main(CallStoredProcedure.java:29)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to call stored procedure with multiple in and out parameters using entity manager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246614/how-to-call-stored-procedure-with-multiple-in-and-out-parameters-using-entity-ma)

Comment: @Todd thanks for suggestion but i am not using entity manager, i have added a simple mapping of stored procedure in hibernate and try to store the result in my bean .

Comment: Any clue how i can solve this?

Comment: Try to add brackets <![CDATA[{CALL  myprocedure(?,?)}]]>